# How to overwrite the watermark timestamp in streaming query?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

How to overwrite the watermark timestamp in streaming query? 
I have used output mode `complete`, but it is still not working .

Comment: Overwrite? Can you elaborate what you're after?

Comment: am reading static files from a directory, am able to read all the files data but not ble to write all the data using structured streaming. Please suggest on how to read the static files data using spark structured streaming

Comment: def readStreamer(filePath: String, formatType: String, schema: Option[StructType] = None)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
  val stream = spark.readStream.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).format(formatType)

  if (schema.nonEmpty) stream.schema(schema.get).load(filePath)
  else stream.load(filePath)
} ...How can i trigger the static files present in a folder using spark streaming job.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you've got already. Please avoid using comments for code sharing. Thanks.